# SU Retag Request: [something-extension(s)] --> [extensions]

Tags: support, status-declined, retag-request

Search for **extension** on https://superuser.com/tags.

Can't these be retagged to [extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extensions), to avoid having [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) and [google-chrome-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extensions) as tags on a post? The search [allows to search for both tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome+google-chrome-extensions) so it shouldn't be a problem.

- [firefox-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox-extensions)
- [google-chrome-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extensions)
- [safari-extensions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/safari-extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree. I think they need to be seperate since they have different focuses, and a Safari Extension will not work in Chrome for example unless it is written for that sole purpose.

Comment: So, the given two Google Chrome questions in [extensions] might instead benefit from being tagged [google-chrome-extensions]?

Comment: @TomWij. It may. I am ok with leaving it but your welcome to manually edit.